# Fundamental Q for windows Virtual Machine VMware :. VMware access and migration between PC's

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, operating-systems, vmware-player

I'm a  total squat far as far as virtual machines are concerned so please bear with me while I explain my problem.

I run into many situation where I actually had to change my physical computer and have to go through the painstaking process of installing Windows & my programs once again.

In this regard I have the following questions for virtual machines :

Can I install programs such as Adobe professional and others that require Licence key on a virtual machine & and then when I change my computer just chg the virtual machine file and all these programs are accessible to me without me having to install them over once again and configure them.

Can my virtual machine installation access physical files on the operating system. Example I have a bunch of documents and PDF files outside in the OS and I would like to open them using my virtual machine  Office.& PDF programs .. is that possible ?

What are some of the actual challenges when using virtual machine as substitute for actual Windows install for your day today productivity desktop.

What about Mac OS can it be installed in the same manner with full functionality. What is the difference between server and player

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the applications on the virtual machine will not notice any change as the virtual machine is exactly the same.

You can access files on the real machine (the host) using a feature of the virtualization software (virtualpc, vmware, whatever) usually using a mapped drive.

The only challenge I can think of is the performance as it decreases a bit and the fact that you cannot use real devices (you wont use your real VGA card if playing games for example).